# Display Fields of Related list in corresponding Page layout

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, salesforce-service-cloud

Can anyone tell me is it possible to display the fields present in a related list in the corresponding page layout ? If yes then how ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to display fields present in related list in the corresponding page layout. However you can create the same field in the object and copy data of the related list field into that.